# Issue using python request module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Good morning,
Since yesterday, I'm having timeouts doing requests to ebay website. The code is simple:

```
import requests
headers = {
        "User-Agent": 
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

htlm=requests.get("https://www.ebay.es",headers=headers).text
```

Tested with google and it works. This is the response I receive:
'\nGateway Timeout - In read \n\n

## Gateway Timeout

\nThe proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

\nReference #1.477f1602.1645295618.7675ccad\n\n'

What happened or changed? How could I solve it?

Comment: Remove the headers and it should work. Is there a reason you need that User-Agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the headers should work. Perhaps they don't like that user agent for some reason.

```
import requests
# headers = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
headers = {}
url = "https://www.ebay.es"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html_text = response.text
```